# how to detect children size change actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

if i got a container,there were children display object in it.
the container's size was decided by the children's size.when the size change i need to do something to fit the new size.

since i didn't find the kind of event to detect it,i use ENTER_FRAME event,that's quite silly.
keep every last frame's size,and compare to current frame.maybe the size changed after you deal with the enter frame event,so in some cases,you might see the correct result in the next frame.

i don't think it's a good solution for a component.give me you ideas,thanks.

Comment: How are the children resized? Do you have any code we could look at?

Comment: How about the Event.RESIZE  and for each child to listen on this event ?

Answer (score 2):

Well there is no standard solution for this. You could create a custom class which overrides the setters of width/height/x/y/scaleX/scaleY/scrollRect .. and maybe some other properties. The children should extend such a class.

I used a boolean to prevent its dispatched multiple times, after a frame the flag will be resetted.

```
override public function set width(value:Number):void
{
    if (value !== super.width && !isNaN(Number(value)) this.dispatchResize();
    super.width = value;
}

override public function set height(value:Number):void
{ 
    if (value !== super.height && !isNaN(Number(value)) this.dispatchResize();
    super.height = value;
}

override public function set scaleX(value:Number):void
{ 
    if (value !== super.scaleX && !isNaN(Number(value)) this.dispatchResize();
    super.scaleX = value;
}

override public function set scaleY(value:Number):void
{ 
    if (value !== super.scaleY && !isNaN(Number(value)) this.dispatchResize();
    super.scaleY = value;
}

private var _hasDispatchedResize:Boolean;
protected function dispatchResize():void
{
   // do something
   if (!this._hasDispatchedResize)
   {
      this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
      this._hasDispatchedResize = true;
      this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrameOnce);
   }
}

private function handleEnterFrameOnce(event:Event):void
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrameOnce);
    this._hasDispatchedResize = false;
}
```

Now, in the container class you can listen to a `Event.RESIZE` of the children. Your not really sure if the value actually changed (in case of a frame change on a MovieClip), but in most cases this will work. I've added an extra check inside this setters before dispatching the resize. It depends on the case if this will suit your case.

Comment: Object over ride things is too bold for me.which means you can't add flash.display.Sprite to my component ,you have to add xxx.MySprite,you can't add flash.display.MovieClip,you have to add xxx.MyMovieClip etc.that's actually expose weak point of OO programming and don't forget remove child and add child ,that also change the size of the object.

Comment: Yes its a limitation, you cannot override using composition. however why would that be a problem for you? Just extend and your done? For other components you could choose to just manually collect the data.

Btw, I was thinking, if you want to use composition, you could also create a behavior class that grabs the rectangle using getRect() or getBounds() every frame and on a difference it dispatches the resize (or does the thing you want to do). That could gives some more control.

Like I said it depends on the case. What are you trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is whatever function resizes the children, add your own dispatch event to it that would broadcast that a size change occurred.

```
//Never forget to import your classes.
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.Event;

//Our custom listener listens for our custom event, then calls the function we
//want called when children are resized.
addEventListener("childResized", honeyIResizedTheChildren);

function resizingLikeFun(){
    datClip.width++;//they be resizin, yo.
    dispatchEvent(new Event("childResized"));//Our custom event
}

function honeyIResizedTheChildren(e:Event){
    trace("Giant Cheerios");
    //Whatever you want to do when the children are resized goes here.
}
```

I assume some things with that code, so let me know if this doesn't fully apply to you.

Comment: sorry buddy,if i know how and when they are resizing,it's wouldn't be a problem.for example,datClip.width++ doesn't mean the object's width really increase one.because you don't know what kind of the object it is.

Comment: @Duke - using strings in events should be avoided, create an Events class which contains the event type eg. Events.ChildResized, substituting Events for whatever name is appropriate

Comment: @Neil Thank you for the tip! I also realized my script is worse than useless since a call to the function would have done the same thing and done it better. I should have seen that sooner, and for that I apologize.

Comment: @Duke hey dude you are trying to help people and for that you are a star!